# ubuntu 18.04 on dell inspiron 15 7000 series: no sound after update

Tags: soundcard

I have ubuntu 18.04.4 on a dell inspiron 15 7000 series. After some updates the sound stopped working. When I do

`aplay -l`

I get the following output

`aplay: device_list:221: no soundcard found...`

When I do 
`lspci -v | grep -A7 -i "audio"`

I get

```
00:1f.3 Multimedia audio controller: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH cAVS (rev 10)
    Subsystem: Dell Device 0922
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 32, IRQ 17
    Memory at ed318000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Memory at ed100000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1M]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: snd_soc_skl
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel, snd_soc_skl, sof_pci_dev
```

I tried different things, like purging and reinstalling pulseaudio and alsa, adding my user to the audio group, and rebooting the system but nothing worked.

I tried to run alsamixer and I get the following

`cannot open mixer: No such file or directory`

when I do

`cat   /proc/asound/cards`

I get

`--- no soundcards ---`

Finally, when I do

`lsmod | grep intel`

I get

```
intel_rapl_msr         20480  0
intel_powerclamp       20480  0
kvm_intel             241664  0
kvm                   651264  1 kvm_intel
ghash_clmulni_intel    16384  0
aesni_intel           372736  4
aes_x86_64             20480  1 aesni_intel
crypto_simd            16384  1 aesni_intel
cryptd                 24576  2 crypto_simd,ghash_clmulni_intel
glue_helper            16384  1 aesni_intel
snd_sof_intel_hda_common    69632  1 sof_pci_dev
snd_sof_intel_hda      20480  1 snd_sof_intel_hda_common
snd_sof_intel_byt      24576  1 sof_pci_dev
snd_sof_intel_ipc      20480  1 snd_sof_intel_byt
snd_sof                98304  4 snd_sof_intel_hda_common,snd_sof_intel_byt,snd_sof_intel_ipc,sof_pci_dev
snd_soc_hdac_hda       24576  2 snd_sof_intel_hda_common,snd_soc_skl
snd_hda_ext_core       28672  5 snd_sof_intel_hda_common,snd_soc_hdac_hdmi,snd_soc_hdac_hda,snd_soc_skl,snd_sof_intel_hda
snd_soc_acpi_intel_match    28672  3 snd_sof_intel_hda_common,sof_pci_dev,snd_soc_skl
snd_soc_acpi           16384  3 snd_soc_acpi_intel_match,sof_pci_dev,snd_soc_skl
snd_soc_core          237568  7 snd_sof,snd_sof_intel_hda_common,snd_soc_hdac_hdmi,snd_soc_hdac_hda,snd_soc_skl,snd_soc_dmic,snd_soc_skl_hda_dsp
intel_cstate           20480  0
snd_hda_intel          53248  0
snd_intel_nhlt         20480  2 snd_hda_intel,snd_soc_skl
snd_hda_codec         131072  5 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_soc_hdac_hda,snd_soc_skl_hda_dsp
snd_hda_core           90112  11 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_ext_core,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_sof_intel_hda_common,snd_soc_hdac_hdmi,snd_soc_hdac_hda,snd_soc_skl,snd_sof_intel_hda,snd_soc_skl_hda_dsp
snd_pcm               102400  10 snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_ext_core,snd_hda_codec,snd_sof,snd_sof_intel_hda_common,snd_soc_hdac_hdmi,snd_soc_core,snd_soc_skl,snd_hda_core,snd_pcm_dmaengine
intel_rapl_perf        20480  0
btintel                24576  1 btusb
intel_wmi_thunderbolt    20480  0
snd                    86016  12 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_seq,snd_seq_device,snd_hwdep,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_timer,snd_compress,snd_soc_core,snd_pcm,snd_rawmidi
bluetooth             573440  28 btrtl,btintel,btbcm,bnep,btusb
intel_lpss_pci         20480  0
intel_lpss             16384  1 intel_lpss_pci
intel_rapl_common      24576  2 intel_rapl_msr,processor_thermal_device
intel_pch_thermal      16384  0
intel_soc_dts_iosf     20480  1 processor_thermal_device
intel_hid              20480  0
sparse_keymap          16384  2 intel_hid,dell_wmi
intel_ishtp_loader     24576  0
intel_ishtp_hid        24576  0
intel_ish_ipc          24576  0
intel_ishtp            49152  4 cros_ec_ishtp,intel_ishtp_hid,intel_ish_ipc,intel_ishtp_loader
hid                   126976  6 i2c_hid,usbhid,hid_multitouch,hid_sensor_hub,intel_ishtp_hid,hid_generic
wmi                    32768  7 intel_wmi_thunderbolt,alienware_wmi,dell_wmi,wmi_bmof,dell_smbios,dell_wmi_descriptor,mxm_wmi
pinctrl_intel          28672  1 pinctrl_cannonlake
```

I tried the command `sudo modprobe -v snd_hda_intel` and got not output.

Finally, when I run the `alsa-info` script I get the following

```
ALSA Information Script v 0.4.64
--------------------------------

This script visits the following commands/files to collect diagnostic
information about your ALSA installation and sound related hardware.

  dmesg
  lspci
  lsmod
  aplay
  amixer
  alsactl
  /proc/asound/
  /sys/class/sound/
  ~/.asoundrc (etc.)

See '/usr/sbin/alsa-info --help' for command line options.

/usr/sbin/alsactl: save_state:1595: No soundcards found...
cat: /tmp/alsa-info.gWUNGfyoPc/alsactl.tmp: No such file or directory
Automatically upload ALSA information to www.alsa-project.org? [y/N] : y
Uploading information to www.alsa-project.org ...  Done!

Your ALSA information is located at http://alsa-project.org/db/?f=fe30241ea3a0bde8037c139efc77729ac6aa8347

Please inform the person helping you.
```

I ran out of ideas. Any help will be very welcome.

Many thanks in advance,

Alejandro

Comment: Also, when I look into the folder `/proc/asound/` there is a file `cards` which only contents are `--- no soundcards ---` . I hope this will give more info for solving the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same issue on Ubuntu 18.04 on my dell vostro 7590 ... Very disturbing . I got my speaker back by doing what was written here https://superuser.com/a/1509313/1151609

but i still have issues with my microphone and with the Bluetooth ...

Those updates are excessively annoying ...

Comment: It would be nice to descripes the relevant part from your link.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I basically just edited the /etc/default/grub file to boot with the correct GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT. The issue should have been fixed recently by an update.